# Работоспособность сервера, рассчет в процентах

Tags: алгоритм, php

Мне нужно рассчитать работоспособность сервера в процентном соотношение за последние 24 часа к примеру. Получить значение работоспособности сервера не проблема, по крону каждые несколько минут проверяется работает сервер или нет и вносится в базу вместе с датой.

А что дальше ? Как определить % рабочего состояния от 24 часов ? Помогите с составлением алгоритма.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как рассчитать кол-во процентов? Из курса алгебры вам должно быть известно, что процентное соотношение находится по простейшей формуле - **опр.количество  / все количество * 100**  =)

Comment: Не совсем подходит, у меня данных есть on/off статус сервера, и располагаться они могут хаотично.

Comment: @tranceman, если опросы хаотичны (случайны), то ничего лучше total/success не придумать.

Или Вы опрашиваете сервер по некоторому расписанию ? Тогда приведите его.

Comment: Время может варьироваться от 1 до 5 минут, в зависимости настроек для определенного сервера.

Comment: @tranceman, при таких малых (по сравнению с 24-мя часами) интервалах для практики не заморачивайтесь, делайте просто - % = (работает \* 100) / количество.

Или Вы какую-то "научную работу" ваяете ?

Пять минут - это 0.35% (точнее 0.003472)) от суток - это порядок цены ошибки измерений. 

А Вы ведь, скорее всего, печатать будете целые проценты.

Answer (score 2):

Опрашиваешь сервер каждый час, в базу пишешь работает он или нет + дата и время проверки.
Теперь, например, за сутки сервер работал 19 часов, из 24, т.е. 5 часов простоя, а это 79% активности.

- Берем 19 часов
- Делим на 24 часа и
     умножаем на 100
- получаем 79%

Comment: Ну вы прям гений математики! Аж в процентах!

Comment: Дак я вообще тупой, на один двойки учился. Спасибо что назвали меня программистом, так меня еще никто не называл :)

Comment: Если вы и правда так о себе думаете, то все действительно очень плохо, @tranceman...

Comment: видимо тут должна была быть одна табличка из одного известного сериала)

Comment: Сарказм - средство умных людей для выживания в мире идиотов (с) @tranceman, браво)

Answer (score 1):

Раз данные по времени распределяются неравномерно, считайте например, по серединам между соседними замерами. Если бы это был график, то были бы столбики высотой 1 или 0 и шириной как я описал. Напр. замеры были в 5, 7 и 13 часов, тогда столбцы за сутки будут: 0..6, 6..10 и 10..24 Их вес в статистике пропорционален длине.

Напр. выборка за сутки у вас находится в массиве, где ключ - время, а значение TRUE или FALSE. Определяем начало и конец периода. Считаем середины между. Складываем длины участков, где TRUE. Делим на общую длину периода, умножаем на 100%, как подсказали эксперты : )

Comment: Автор пишет

    Время может варьироваться от 1 до 5 минут, в зависимости настроек для определенного сервера.

т.е. для каждого сервера равномерно. Очевидно, что надо считать для каждого сервера свой процент. Поэтому все тривиально - Success/Total